# Populate csv file when query to service returned result

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-mvc, asynchronous

I my spring mvc controller I am going to make call to our Service, that should return result of query, that runs up to 30 secs.

I would like to populate csv file in controller with  results of query for user to download. How can I know when the query is finished to start populating the file?

Could you give me any tips of how can I implement this task without blocking the thread ? So user will be able to continue interacting with web site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this using ThreadPoolTaskExecutor and SpringBatch. Spring batch reader reads data from db then writer will write the same in csv file. And spring batch is triggered asynchronously using ThreadpoolTaskexecutor from my webApp. This way, no web thread is blocked.